# Reverse words in Java

Tags: java, strings

Short and Spicy question is that If input is `how are you` and output should be`you are how`.

```
public class ReverseWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String input;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the input string");
        input = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enterd String:"+input);
        System.out.println("Reversed:"+reverse(input));
    }

    public static String reverse(String input){
        String delimiter = " ";
        String[] splits = input.split(delimiter);
        String reverse = new String("");
        for(int i=splits.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            //System.out.println(splits[i]);
            reverse += splits[i];
            reverse = reverse.concat(delimiter);
        }
        System.out.println(reverse);
        return reverse;
    }
}
```

How can I improve my code? And Is there any other way to do it with less time and space complexity?

Comment: for a lot of concatenation, it's better to use a StringBuilder performance wise (time/memory).

Comment: How `reverse` should behave if input isn't `how are you` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The odd behaviour is that the result gets printed twice: once in `reverse()`, and again in `main()`.  `reverse()` should be fixed so that it returns the result without printing it.

The output will also include an extra space at the end.  It may be invisible, but I would consider it technically incorrect.

Your code, with those issues fixed, and a few tweaks:

```
public static String reverse(String input) {
    String delimiter = " ";                        
    String[] splits = input.split(delimiter);
    String reverse = "";                            // Same as new String("")
    for (int i = splits.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {   // Be more generous with spaces
        reverse += splits[i] + delimiter;           // Get rid of .concat()
    }
    if (splits.length > 0) {
        reverse += splits[0];
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

However, repeated string concatenation is inefficient: every `+=` involves allocating a new buffer and copying everything.  You should really be using a `StringBuilder`, [like this](/a/60913/9357).  (Other suggested solutions in that question are also quite good.  You should study those answers and form your own opinion.)

Comment: Thanks Sir. It is really helpful. But I don't understand the reason to get rid of concat. please explain

Comment: What I mean is that `.concat()` is more commonly and succinctly written as `+`.

Answer (score 3):

There are variety of ways of doing it.

If you want to use library methods, then here is a short solution:-

```
public static String reverse(String input) {
    String[] words = input.trim().split(" ");
    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(words));
    return String.join(" ", words);
}
```

If you want to do most of the stuff by yourself, which probably would be faster(tested on 22 test cases), then here is another solution:-

```
public String reverse(String s) {
    s = s.trim();
    char[] str = s.toCharArray();
    // first reverse the entire array
    reverseHelper(str,0,str.length -1);
    int cur = 0, i = 0, start = 0, end =0;
    while( i < str.length){
        while( i < str.length && str[i] == ' ') i++;
        start = i;
        while(i < str.length && str[i] != ' ') i++;
        end = i-1;
        // now reverse each word separately
        reverseHelper(str,start, end);

        // this makes sure that the multiple spaces are removed
        //"how are    you"  is converted to "you are how"
        for(int a = cur, b = start; b <= end; a++, b++)
            str[a] = str[b];

        cur = cur + end - start +2;
        if(cur -1 <str.length )
            str[cur - 1] = ' ';

    }
    while(cur < s.length()){
        str[cur++] = ' '; 
    }
    String result = new String(str);
    return result.trim();

}


private static void reverseHelper(char[] s, int a, int b) {
    for(int i = a, j = b; i < j ; i++, j--){
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. You said that you tested on 22 cases. how did you do these tests? Any tools? Or just by checking the console to know the run time.

Comment: I'm not sure speed is the point here - the user input would definitely be the bottleneck... Further, how did you benchmark this? Using a benchmarking framework like JMH or by hand? If the latter, then the numbers are likely wrong anyway...

Comment: I tested it by running on this Online Judge https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-words-in-a-string/
Since this website is quite reliable, I assume that their test cases are far better than what I could have come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Although I like @maxomax answer and prefer to let the Lava libraries do what they are good at. Below is my answer without the libraries.

Things I changed.

- Moved the delimiter to `private static final`
- Added `finally` block to close the `BufferedReader`
- Used `StringBuilder` with a predetermined size.

  ```
  public class ReverseWord
  {
      private static final String DELIMITER = " ";

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
      {
          String input;
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          System.out.println("Enter the input string");
          try
          {
              input = br.readLine().trim();
              System.out.println("Enterd String:" + input);
              System.out.println("Reversed:" + reverse(input));
          }
          finally
          {
              br.close();
          }
      }

      public static String reverse(String input)
      {
          String[] splits = input.split(DELIMITER);
          StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(input.length() + 1);
          for(int i=splits.length-1; i>=0; i--)
          {
              reverse.append(splits[i]).append(DELIMITER);
          }
          return reverse.toString().trim();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I understand first two points. What difference will be there by adding  capacity to StringBuilder? Please tell me

Comment: It's for the capacity of letters the string builder can handle. Every time you call `.append()` it checks the size, if it's not enough it news up the object causing more gc's and more cycles. `StringBuffer` does the same and since string concats use `StringBuffer` under the covers... well it just speeds up processing and gc's so if you know your capacities use them. Same for any of the Collection API's and arrays.